# Can we use tikz draw SEM?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I want to know if there are any better methods? Especially I will draw many SEMs and they are different. How to label these curved arrows conveniently use those numbers? Why don't the arrows link toghether with the ellipse?

```
 \documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
%draw circles
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\draw (\i,10.5) circle [radius=0.3];
%draw rectangles
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\draw (\i-0.4,9) rectangle (\i+0.4,9.4);
%draw ellipses
\draw (3,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (8.5,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (14,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (19.5,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (25,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (30.5,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
% draw arrows
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\draw [-latex] (\i,10.2) -- (\i,9.4);
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
\draw [-latex] (3,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\foreach \i in {6,...,11}
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\foreach \i in {12,...,16}
\draw [-latex] (14,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\foreach \i in {17,...,22}
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\foreach \i in {23,...,27}
\draw [-latex] (25,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\foreach \i in {28,...,33}
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\node (a) at (3,5.4) {};
\node (b) at (8.5,5.4) {};
\node (c) at (14,5.4) {};
\node (d) at (19.5,5.4) {};
\node (e) at (25,5.4) {};
\node (f) at (30.5,5.4) {};
%\draw[<->,-latex] (a) -- (b);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (a) edge (b);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (b) edge (c);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (c) edge (d);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (d) edge (e);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (e) edge (f);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (a) edge (c);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (a) edge (d);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (a) edge (e);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (a) edge (f);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (b) edge (c);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (b) edge (d);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (b) edge (e);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (b) edge (f);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (c) edge (d);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (c) edge (e);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (c) edge (f);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (d) edge (e);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (d) edge (f);
\draw[<->,bend right]  (e) edge (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to know if someone have done this work and I will try to give a minimal working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with `LuaLaTeX`:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,arrows.meta,quotes,shapes.geometric}
\usegdlibrary{layered,trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]
\graph [tree layout,
  edge quotes mid, edge quotes={
    fill=white, font=\tiny, shape=circle, inner sep=0
  }, 
  sibling distance=0.1cm, sibling sep=0.1cm, component sep=0.1cm,
  level 1/.style={nodes={ellipse, draw}},
  level 2/.style={nodes={rectangle, draw, font=\tiny}},
  level 3/.style={nodes={circle, draw, inner sep=0.05cm}, target edge style={<-}},
  level distance=1.5cm, 
  grow=up
]
{
  F1 ->[".81"] q1 -> e1;
  F1 ->[".83"] q2 -> e2;
  F1 ->[".81"] q3 -> e3;
  F1 ->[".71"] q4 -> e4;
  F1 ->[".74"] q5 -> e5;
  %
  F2 ->[".80"] q6  -> e6;
  F2 ->[".82"] q7  -> e7;
  F2 ->[".82"] q8  -> e8;
  F2 ->[".80"] q9  -> e9;
  F2 ->[".78"] q10 -> e10;
  F2 ->[".82"] q11  -> e11;
  %
  F3 ->[".88"] q12 -> e12;
  F3 ->[".82"] q13 -> e13;
  F3 ->[".83"] q14 -> e14;
  F3 ->[".84"] q15 -> e15;
  F3 ->[".88"] q16 -> e16;
  %
  F4 ->[".85"] q17 -> e17;
  F4 ->[".88"] q18 -> e18;
  F4 ->[".85"] q19 -> e19;
  F4 ->[".77"] q20 -> e20;
  F4 ->[".76"] q21 -> e21;
  F4 ->[".63"] q22 -> e22;
  %
  F5 ->[".85"] q23 -> e23;
  F5 ->[".88"] q24 -> e24;
  F5 ->[".85"] q25 -> e25;
  F5 ->[".77"] q26 -> e26;
  F5 ->[".76"] q27 -> e27;
  %
  F6 ->[".85"] q28 -> e28;
  F6 ->[".88"] q29 -> e29;
  F6 ->[".85"] q30 -> e30;
  F6 ->[".77"] q31 -> e31;
  F6 ->[".76"] q32 -> e32;
  F6 ->[".63"] q33 -> e33;
};
\graph [edge quotes={font=\small, above=0.125cm, inner sep=0},
   edges={out=300, in=240}]{
  (F1) <->[".70"] (F2);
  (F1) <->[".72"] (F3);
  (F1) <->[".74"] (F4);
  (F1) <->[".76"] (F5);
  (F1) <->[".78"] (F6);
  (F2) <->[".80"] (F3);
  (F2) <->[".82"] (F4);
  (F2) <->[".84"] (F5);
  (F2) <->[".86"] (F6);
  (F3) <->[".90"] (F4);
  (F3) <->[".92"] (F5);
  (F3) <->[".94"] (F6);
  (F4) <->[".10"] (F5);
  (F4) <->[".12"] (F6);
  (F5) <->[".20"] (F6);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to decrease the length of arrows of the third level（between e1 and q1）

Comment: @dozer add (e.g.) `level distance=0.5cm` to the `level 2` style

Comment: Can we rotate the model 90 degree clockwise or counterclockwise

Answer (score 2):

This kind of flowchart may be a good opportunity to use this [tikz graphical editor](https://github.com/yishn/tikzcd-editor).

It is described as:

> A simple visual editor for creating commutative diagrams.

You can host your own instance by following the install steps on the GitHub repo or you can [try it online](http://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/).

Once you are happy with your diagram, you can copy the code and paste it in your LaTeX document. The generated code works with the `tikz-cd` package :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

%% paste the generated code here.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\newcommand{\jiuhao}{\fontsize{2.55pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\shihao}{\fontsize{1.2pt}{\baselineskip}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
%draw circles
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\draw (\i,10.5) circle [radius=0.3] node[font=\jiuhao] {e{\i}};
%draw rectangles
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\draw (\i-0.4,9) rectangle (\i+0.4,9.4) ;
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\node at (\i,9.2)[font=\jiuhao]{q{\i}};
%draw ellipses
\draw (3,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (8.5,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (14,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (19.5,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (25,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
\draw (30.5,6) ellipse (1 and 0.6);
% draw arrows
\foreach \i in {1,...,33}
\draw [-latex] (\i,10.2) -- (\i,9.4);
%\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
%\draw [-latex] (3,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\draw [-latex] (3,6.6) to node[fill=white, font=\shihao]{.88} (1,9);
\draw [-latex] (3,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (2,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (3,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (3,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (3,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (4,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (3,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (5,9);
\foreach \i in {6,...,11}
%\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6) to node[fill=white, font=\shihao]{.88} (6,9);
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (7,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (8,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (9,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (10,9);
\draw [-latex] (8.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (11,9);
\foreach \i in {12,...,16}
%\draw [-latex] (14,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\draw [-latex] (14,6.6) to node[fill=white, font=\shihao]{.88} (12,9);
\draw [-latex] (14,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (13,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (14,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (14,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (14,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (15,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (14,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (16,9);
\foreach \i in {17,...,22}
%\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6) to node[fill=white, font=\shihao]{.88} (17,9);
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (18,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (19,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (20,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (21,9);
\draw [-latex] (19.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (22,9);
\foreach \i in {23,...,27}
%\draw [-latex] (25,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\draw [-latex] (25,6.6) to node[fill=white, font=\shihao]{.88} (23,9);
\draw [-latex] (25,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (24,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (25,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (25,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (25,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (26,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (25,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (27,9);
\foreach \i in {28,...,33}
%\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6) -- (\i,9);
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6) to node[fill=white, font=\shihao]{.88} (28,9);
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (29,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (30,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (31,9) ;
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (32,9);
\draw [-latex] (30.5,6.6)  to node[fill=white,font=\shihao]{.88} (33,9);
\node[above] (a) at (3,5.4) {F1};
\node[above] (b) at (8.5,5.4) {F2};
\node [above](c) at (14,5.4) {F3};
\node [above](d) at (19.5,5.4) {F4};
\node[above] (e) at (25,5.4) {F5};
\node[above] (f) at (30.5,5.4) {F6};
%\draw[<->,-latex] (a) -- (b);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (a) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (b) ;
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (b) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (c);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (c) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (d);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (d) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (e);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (e) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (f);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (a) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (c);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (a) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (d);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (a) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (e);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (a) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (f);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (b) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (d);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (b) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (e);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (b) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (f);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (c) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (e);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (c) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (f);
\draw[<->,>=latex,bend right]  (d) to node[fill=white,font=\jiuhao] {.88} (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: welcome better methods.

Comment: I want to resize the label box, I hope the label box become smaller and the font become larger.